# C# JSON & Parsing

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization, windows-phone-8

I have managed to set-up a simple `webClient` that calls my WCF service in a WP8 application. The method fires perfectly fine and the data is returned via the `OpenReadCompleted` event.

What I wish to do now is convert the returned data which is in JSON and populate a collection of objects.

This is the `webClient` code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var uri = new Uri("urlGoesHere");
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += webClient_OpenReadCompleted;
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
}
```

This is the `OpenReadComplete` code:

```
void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var sr = new StreamReader(e.Result);
    var data = sr.ReadToEnd();
    //ToDo - Create a collection of SightingTypes and populate
    sr.Close();
    sr.Dispose();
}
```

And this is the POCO/Object which I want populating:

```
public class SightingType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BrandId { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

When I hover over data, I can see the following (shortened):

```
{\"Message\":null,\"Status\":0,\"CurrentVersionNumber\":26,\"SightingTypes\":[{\"BrandId\":\"brands\\/1\",\"DestinationUserIds\":[\"users\\/33\"],\"Id\":\"SightingTypes\\/8\",\"IsDeleted\":false,\"IsEnabled\":true,\"Name\":\"Michael Johnson\"}
```

What I am particularly interested in is the **Name** and the **BrandId**.

Comment: You can try Json.NET http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and following classes (your root object is not *SightingType* )....

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(data);
```

---

```
public class SightingType
{
    public string BrandId { get; set; }
    public List<string> DestinationUserIds { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public object Message { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int CurrentVersionNumber { get; set; }
    public List<SightingType> SightingTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Also see [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) where you can get the class definitions for your json string

Comment: Wow. That worked! Very nicely done. Can you please explain a little how that works?

Comment: @Subby just put your json into the `http://json2csharp.com/` which creates the classes for you. Other part is the Json.Net's magic..

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking out [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/). It comes with a JSON Serializer that should meet your need:

```
SightingType deserializedSightingType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SightingType>(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code to parse JSON into POCO

```
        //get the JSON string into 'responseText'

        // Deserialize response Message to JsonResponse
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jsonResponse = serializer.Deserialize<JsonResponse>(responseText);

        // where in <> put your class 'SightingType'
```

you will need to add resource System.Web.Extensions.dll in order to use  JavaScriptSerializer class

Comment: I can't find System.Web.Extensions when I try adding a reference.

Comment: I found the DLL and tried adding it but i got an error: A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.